# Check how app looks on different APi versions / screen resolutions

Tags: android, api, resolution

does anyone know if there is somewhere a utility that helps to make sure that an android application works / looks fine on different resolutions / android versions?

I would need something like http://browsershots.org/ but for android apps.
Any hints?

Comment: Having a such utility will be a good news to the android developer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the emulator. Set up one AVD per resolution and OS version you are interested in, and run your app in each.

Some of the "test my app on a bunch of devices" services (e.g., TestDroid, apkudo, LessPainful) may accomplish similar aims, though you would have to check out their service features and device fleet to see if one meets your needs.

Comment: Yes, i know the emulators, but they are so incredible slow :(

Comment: @nr1, slow but free. If Google makes the emulator as good as the real device, no developer will by the real device :)

Comment: If you upgrade to the newest SDK version the emulater/devices has a resume-function which cuts a lot of boot time and frustration.